# Is there a bare bones sample WPF sample App?

Tags: wpf

I am looking for a sample line of business app that has source code available. I am just starting out with WPF so something with a GUI that add, update and delete from a db will be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a well-reviewed and highly rated article from [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx) that demonstrates CRUD operations with a WPF grid against a simple Customer->Order db. It's bare boned but covers the subject in great detail and depth (probably why you're not having luck finding simple samples. WPF defies simple, but for the better, making you structure your code well right from the start.)

If you want quick and dirty, you might want to take a peek [here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/50edf0a7-5667-4a72-802b-974d1e0aa9bf/)

There's also a little [StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247225/simple-crud-work-with-wpf-and-data-binding) you might want to follow up on.